How to automate Jupyter notebook runs?
I have a general question. I often use Jupyter notebooks for prototyping. I am looking for practical ways to go to production. I know this might not be ideal, but as those are hobby notebooks, I'd like some practical solution.
So I was wondering what are the ways to:

Automate notebooks runs entirely at given times (ideally with a cron format)
Having some information (mail, notification) about whether it has runs or not and results


You might want to have a look at papermill, which is made to parameterize and execute notebooks.
You can either

run noteboos from a python script or
use the command line interface

I hope this helps.
One remark
I don't know your use case, but as a remark: in most cases python scripts might be better suited for a cron job than notebooks.

Usecases seems interesting. I will check further. Not sure it is what I am looking for. I think I was mostly looking for the architecture solution to not have my computer running for this to work.
